# How to Read data from 2 different Firebase database which are from 2 different projects

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Basically i want to access two different databases form two different projects in firebase from one flutter app,
For more info ,
I have build a single Flutter app in which ,
 some time i want to refer to one database of (Project name "A" ) and some time i need to refer another database of (Project name "B") ,
is there a way to refer to 2 different database at a time in single app.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to read data from 2 different Firebase databases through a single app. Simply go to your Home page on your Firebase console and app your app (both iOS and Android, I assume, since you are developing with Flutter) for both databases.